# How can I join data like this in SQL Server, then display in my app?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to figure out how to query two columns from a table and then join the results to records from a different table and then display these items in a gridview using Visual Studio (Express 2013 for Web).

Additional explanation:

I have several projects in a project_table that each have a unique Project_ID. The Project_ID from the project_table is a foreign key to the Project_Codes_table. Each Project_Code has a unique Project_Code_ID. Each Project can have several different Project_Codes associated with it. The results in the gridview should be similar to

```
| Project ID | ProjCode1 | ProjCode2 | ProjCode3 |
```

But, only if the Project_ID was found in the Project_Codes table.

I am assuming that I can get each Project_Code in its own query by getting the value if the Project_Code_ID matches a certain value ... each query could then be tied to the project_table so that I could display the values in a row. I have a pretty good idea how to do this in something like Microsoft Access but I have very little clue how to even attempt this using SQL or Visual Studio.

Comment: It would be nice if you supplied the exact SQL you use to query your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LINQ to SQL`, and set the datagridview.datasource = the query result

1. Right click on your project in solution explorer, and click add new
   item... Select Linq To SQL classes.
2. From the server explorer, either use your existing data connection or right click and add new data connection. Connect to your sql database.
3. Navigate through the data connection until you see the tables you want to query from. Drag each table included in the query to the data classses pane.

In your code where you want to populate the datatable, put similar code

```vb
Using dc As New DataClasses1
    Dim res = From pt In dc.project_table
              Join pc In dc.Project_codes On pc.ID Equals pt.Project_Code_ID
              Select New With {
                  .ProjectID = pc.ID,
                  .ProjectCode1 = pc.ProjCode1
                  } ' etc.
    DataGridView1.DataSource = res
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation and example code. I will be back in the office Monday and will try to implement a solution with linq ... I can also provide an example of what I have versus what I want ... I was having difficulty even knowing how to ask my question.